# WebdriverIO, Mocha, Chia Error using browers.getTitle and assert.strictEqual

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to run a test using Mocha, Chai, and WebdriverIO that asserts that the title of the website [www.travellifemedia.com](http://www.travellifemedia.com) is equal to what the title should be using browser.getTitle and strictEqual.  Getting an error as seen in screenshot and not sure were I am messing up.

````
const assert = require('assert');
var chai = require('chai');




describe('Travel Life Media Homepage Test', () => {
    it('should have the right title', () => {
        const url = browser.url('https://www.travellifemedia.com/');
        const title = browser.getTitle();
        assert.strictEqual(title, 'Travel Life Media: Tourism Marketing');
    })
    it('should save a screenshot of the browser view', function () {
        browser.saveScreenshot('./screenshots/screenshot.png');
    });
    it('should detect if an element is clickable', () => {
        const el = $('.ab_b')
        let clickable = el.isClickable();
        console.log(clickable); // outputs: true or false

        // wait for element to be clickable
        browser.waitUntil(() => el.isClickable())
    });
})```

[Image of Error in VSCode][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW2vN.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Use an **await** keyword

```
const url = await browser.url("<url>")
const browserTitle = await browser.getTitle()
assert.strictEqual(title, 'Travel Life Media: Tourism Marketing');
```

The reason you are getting a Promise pending is due to the 'await' meaning as an Async, it is unable to get the value before it has been resolved.